# findManyToManyRowset with Zend_Db_Table_Select

Tags: zend-framework, many-to-many

I'm trying to use a select object to filter the results of a many to many rowset. This call works great:

```
$articles = $this->model->findArticlesViaArticlesUsers();
```

This however does not:

```
$articles = new Default_Model_Articles();
$articleSelect = $articles->select();
$articleSelect->where("status = 'published'")
              ->order("date_published DESC")
              ->limit(1);

$articles = $this->model->findArticlesViaArticlesUsers($articleSelect);
```

That throws the following error:

> exception 'Zend_Db_Select_Exception'
>   with message 'You cannot define a
>   correlation name 'i' more than once'

I can't figure out how to successfully get "articles that have the status of 'published'" using the magic many-to-many relationship (nor `findManyToManyRowset`). I'm at the end of my rope and thinking of just writing the sql manually. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining the select statement, you must use the same object that you call findManyToManyRowset (or whatever magic function you use) on.

Ex:

```
$articles = new Default_Model_Articles();
$user = $articles->find($userId)->current();
$select = $user->select();
$select->where('status = ?', 'published');
$articles = $user->findArticlesViaArticlesUsers($select);
```

Notice the select statement and findArticlesViaArticlesUsers are both extending $user. Thats the key.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misunderstood how the relationships work.

See [this manual page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html#zend.db.table.relationships.fetching.many-to-many) - you should call the magic method, findArticlesViaArticlesUsers, on a Row object. In this case, I think you want to find a User, and then call findArticles... on that.

Comment: Sorry, it's confusing, I used "model" as my object key [partialLoop()->setObjectKey("model")] in partialLoop

Comment: Plus, as I said in the OP, it works as expended *without* passing a select object. I can get a rowset of the user's articles, but not a "filtered" rowset.